# Something about html usemap

Tags: html

[image: Screenshot]

This is my webpage. The first picture is made with `usemap`, and I made an area for each one of those people. When I click on each one, it loads the description in a different tab, and I don't want that.

So, can I load the description and the name of the men there in the bottom table, at the `click` event on that photo?

```html
<img src="http://mythologica.ro/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/zei-egipteni2-1280x640.jpg" style="height:60%; width:80%" alt="zeii" usemap="#mapazei">

<map name="mapazei">
  <area shape="rect" coords="50,80,280,605" alt="primu" href="1.html">
  <area shape="rect" coords="300,80,500,605" alt="primu" href="2.html">
  <area shape="rect" coords="490,80,680,605" alt="primu" href="3.html">
  <area shape="rect" coords="680,80,830,605" alt="primu" href="4.html">
  <area shape="rect" coords="840,80,1030,605" alt="primu" href="5.html">
  <area shape="rect" coords="1050,80,1230,605" alt="primu" href="6.html">
</map>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="20%">name</td>
    <td width="80">description</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The coords may not work in this snippet because the photo I have saved on my PC has a different resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Event Delegation

Register the `<map>` to the click event and then arrange `if/else` conditionals so that `<area>` is the only tag considered clicked. The information was missing so I added `data-name` and `data-dom` to each `<area>`. Also the `<area>` `href` were set to jump to another page. You can't have a click transfer info to a `<table>` and go to another page, you must decide on one or the other. So the `href` no longer jump to a page, this is done by doing this: `href="#/"`.

---

### Demo

**Details are commented in demo**
**Note:** The `<area>`s `rect` are overlapping because of the small scale, so review it in full page.

```js
// Reference the <map> 
var map = document.querySelector('map');

// This is the Event Handler - passing the Event Object
function identify(event) {
  // Clicked element (i.e. <area>)
  var eTgt = event.target;
  // Registered element (i.e. <map>)
  var eCur = event.currentTarget;

  /*
  if clicked element is NOT the registered element...
  */
  if (eTgt !== eCur) {
    // if the clicked element is an <area>...
    if (eTgt.tagName === "AREA") {
      // Get its data-name...
      var name = eTgt.dataset.name;
      //...and data-dom
      var domain = eTgt.dataset.dom;
      // Reference the <table>
      var table = document.querySelector('table');
      // Locate the appropriate <td>
      var nameCell = table.rows[1].cells[0];
      var domCell = table.rows[1].cells[1];
      // Change the <td> content to the associated values
      nameCell.textContent = name;
      domCell.textContent = domain;
    }
  }
}

/*
Register the <map> to the click event...
when clicked event handler function identify() is called
*/
map.onclick = identify;
```

```html
<img src="http://mythologica.ro/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/zei-egipteni2-1280x640.jpg" style="height:65.25%; width:100%" alt="zeii" usemap="#mapazei">

<map name="mapazei">
  <area href="#/" shape="rect" coords="50,80,280,605" alt="primu" data-name='Bast' data-dom='Goddess of Cats'>
    
  <area href="#/" shape="rect" coords="300,80,500,605" alt="primu" data-name='Isis' data-dom='Goddess of Fertility'>
    
  <area href="#/" shape="rect" coords="490,80,680,605" alt="primu" data-name='Ra' data-dom='God of the Sun'>
    
  <area href="#/" shape="rect" coords="680,80,830,605" alt="primu" data-name='Horus' data-dom='God of the Sky'>
    
  <area href="#/" shape="rect" coords="840,80,1030,605" alt="primu" data-name='Hathor?' data-dom='?'>
    
  <area href="#/" shape="rect" coords="1050,80,1230,605" alt="primu" data-name='Anubis or Set?' data-dom='God of the Dead or Evil'>
  </map>

<table border="1" style='transform:translateY(-50px)'>
  <tr>
    <th width="20%">Name</th>
    <th width="80">Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're very welcome. I am a lord as are you, Your Lordship. 